# function that finds the cutoff frequency for low pass filter (in matlab)

Tags: matlab, frequency, lowpass-filter

I want to find the cutoff frequency for a lot of low pass filters. Therefor I want a function that can do that for me. I can make a Bode plot and find the frequency for -3dB, but that is boring and time-consuming. Does someone know how I can automatic this procedure? I was trying with

```
[mag,phase] = bode(sys)
```

but failed. How should I go about this?

I have filter coefficients `a`,`b` available. I try to use some different technique when I discretize the transform function, therefore I want the cutoff frequency empirically from EKV:

```
y_k = b(1)*x_k + b(2)*x_{k-1} – a(2)*y_{k-1}
```

Comment: Which form of the filters is available? Transfer function? Filter coefficients?

Comment: If you information about the type of filter design, you'd probably be better off finding the -3 dB point analytically, rather than hunting for it empirically. Please give more information, or some example code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [bandwidth](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/control/ref/bandwidth.html) command on LTI objects (transfer functions, etc.):

```
G = tf(1, [1 1])
bandwidth(G)

ans =

    0.9976
```

Comment: Can I make bandwith(G) easily work with HP,BP,BS-filter (as it does with LP-filter)?

Comment: Not directly, since the description says "...the gain drops below 70.79 percent (-3 dB) of its DC value". For example, the DC value of an HP filter is 0, so this command would not work.  However, for an HP filter, 1-HP is a LP filter for which the command would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the Control System Toolbox you can do it like that:

```
% some filter
[b, a] = butter(5, 0.6);

% Determine frequency response
[h, w] = freqz(b, a, 2048);

% linear approximation of 3 dB cutoff frequency
ind = find(abs(h) < sqrt(1/2), 1, 'first');
slope = (abs(h(ind)) - abs(h(ind - 1))) / (w(ind) - w(ind - 1));
w_3dB = ( sqrt(1/2) - abs(h(ind - 1)) + slope * w(ind - 1) ) / slope;

% check result
figure; plot(w,abs(h))
hold on;
plot(w_3dB, sqrt(1/2), 'rx');
```

Addmitedly, you'll need the DSP Toolbox for `freqz()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in matlab that can give you your cutoff frequency and its called 'freqz'

If you already know your filter coefficients 'a' and 'b'. Then freqz provides two variable outputs. One variable stores the complex magnitude gain and the other variable stores the normalized frequencies. Essentially all you would need to do is a run a loop that finds the gain that is closest to your passband gain minus 3dB. Then read off the according index for your frequency variable and you have your answer.